# Amazon queue - is it possible to pass an XML object to the queue rather than string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sqs

i'm currently doing a project related to AWS and at some point will need to pass different kind of messages to SQS queue. I don't want to pass the messages as strings but would rather place the objects converted to xml format by jaxb for instance, e.g. writer. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since XML *is* a string, you can just pas a string of XML data. Only the sending and receiving applications need to be aware that the string is XML. Everything else can treat it just like any other string.

You just need to serialize / de-serialize the message to and from XML, which it sounds like you are looking to do anyways.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. It made me wonder though, sorry i'm still learning, but what's the point in converting it to string represented as xml if the message is going to be passed as string anyway?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. It made me wonder though,what's the point in converting it to string represented as xml if the message is going to be passed as string anyway

Comment: You are not representing a string as XML...you are using XML to represent whatever _data_ you want to pas via SQS messages. The message payload _is_ that _XML representation_ of whatever "message" you are using. XML, by it's very nature, is a string-based serialization of data structures.

Comment: the only available data type which can be used to pass the body of a message is String though, if i serialize String,i get another data type

Comment: It seems that you are not understanding what I am saying. XML _is already_ a string. Please learn more about what XML is and how to use it as an SQS message payload. If you still have questions, please ask those questions here on SO.